# Maths riddle - what am I?

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> I can make you dizzy
>   I can ready athletes for games
>   I can shave sheep
>   I can show you images on screens
>   And with my help... you will see the truth when things go wrong
>   I can even do a mixture of all these things at the same time
>   And yet despite all of these things which I can do
>   I do not have the heart or soul to be able to move anyone or anything

What am I?

Hint:

> I can be represented by a film

Comment: Note that the answer to this riddle is related to a part of maths which may not be widely studied, hence the tag. However, programmers may also have come across it.

Comment: *Tries to shave a sheep with a fractal* -  Nope.  That's not it.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha The non-differentiability of a fractal should make it sharp enough to cut through anything, no?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Credit goes to @ffao for the help with this

Is the answer

> a linear transformation

Reasons:

> All the lines are talking about different kinds of linear transformations.

I can make you dizzy

> *Rotation* can make people dizzy.

I can ready athletes for games

> *Stretching* helps athletes get ready for games.

I can shave sheep

> *Shearing* is the act of shaving sheep.

I can show you images on screens

> *Projection* is how you show images on screens.

And with my help... you will see the truth when things go wrong

> *Reflection* can help you figure problems out.

I can even do a mixture of all these things at the same time

> The combination of two or more linear transformations is still a linear transformation.

And yet despite all of these things which I can do
I do not have the heart or soul to be able to move anyone or anything

> When you move something you are causing it to suffer *translation*, which is not a linear transformation.

And for the hint

> All linear transformations can be represented by a matrix. The Matrix is a film

Comment: For 3/ what about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix. And maybe Spin Matrix for 1/, and stretch matrix for 2/

Comment: For 5th one, Vector(1d matrix) is represented with an arrow. Signs with arrows can show you directions when you are lost etc.

Comment: What about "projection matrix" for no 4 ? "inverse matrix" for wrong=>truth ? "matrix multiplication" for the mixture thing ?

Comment: And maybe "nilpotent matrix" for the final one.

Comment: Ouch you're close. You got the right film, but the rest is off as the answer isn't matrix (but you're close). Keep trying!

Comment: As for the comments here, I shall refuse to comment on them :)

Comment: Not sure about what is proper etiquette on this, but I suggested an edit, @SGR can accept it if he thinks it makes sense

Comment: Congratulations!! You have it. Very nicely done! Note that without the last line of the riddle, the answer could've been an affine transformation too.

Answer (score 2):

1. > Monitor as if we keep on looking it makes us dizzy
2. > We can monitor the Atheletes before the games to ready them
3. > Not sure - needed for list to work
4. > Monitor can also show our images on screen
5. > We can see the images on the monitor through cctv

Not sure about 3

Comment: I edited some spoiler markup into your answer - for future reference, you can do this with >! at the beginning of a line, followed by your text. Two spaces at the end of a line will give you a linebreak.

Comment: Thanks for the clean up. I tried putting those as spoilers but was not sure how to do it. Now i know I will apply that. Thanks

Comment: OK, sorry, I changed it again - I realized that SE's markup autocorrects numbered lists to be in sequence, so while your raw text says 1. 2. 4. 5., it decided to number them 1. 2. 3. 4.

Comment: Sorry - but not the answer I was looking for. (btw can u put a spoiler at the top saying what your answer was - I had to look for a while to see it)

Comment: Am i on the right track or way offff?

Comment: I feel like it might be the wrong rabbit hole.  Especially - the math tag implies that these words mean more than they appear to...

Comment: Unfortunately, you re way off. Khale_Kitha's right - the answer is math related. I've added a comment explaining this too.

Answer (score 2):

It might be

> Injection

I can make you dizzy

> Certain drugs can make you dizzy when injected

I can ready athletes for games

> Some athletes inject various drugs, including (but not limited to) HGH, in order to perform better on the playing field

I can shave sheep

> *["The CSIRO in Australia has developed a non-mechanical method of shearing sheep using an injected protein that creates a natural break in the wool fibres."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep_shearing#Wool_removal)*

I can show you images on screens

> I... don't know this one

And with my help... you will see the truth when things go wrong

> This is very likely related to drugs

I can even do a mixture of all these things at the same time
And yet despite all of these things which I can do
I do not have the heart or soul to be able to move anyone or anything

> It follows from the above that these effects could be combined with certain injections

The hint:

> [It can be represented by a film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2248847/)

From the comments:

*"Note that the answer to this riddle is related to a part of maths which may not be widely studied, hence the tag. However, programmers may also have come across it."*

> For math - [I couldn't begin to explain this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection#Injection); for computer-related topics, there is [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Nice try, but again not the answer I'm looking for sorry :). In addition, it doesn't satisfy the hint.

Comment: @QuestionAsker Oh, it does, I just forgot to add [it](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2248847/) to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its right, but could it be

> Simulation?

Because

1. > Space shuttle simulation makes you dizzy.
2. > Bio-mechanical simulator can prepare athletes analyzes performance of an athlete and helps them improve.
3. > Robotics simulation can transfer skills to a robot, which helps with shaving sheep (?)
4. > Ties to **2.**, most simulations can be displayed with a screen. (e.g. Golf Simulator, Game ... etc)
5. > When things go not as expected, some Bayesian or Monte Carlo simulation can often point to the true answer.
6. > Simulations, after all, is a computer iterative process or a program, which doesn't have an heart or soul to begin with.

And finally

> Film simulation is a technique in Lightroom to enhance a picture quality.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I haven't checked this in the last few days. Unfortunately, that's not the answer I'm looking for either. The answer to this riddle is maths related, I'm afraid (That math tag is very important in this case).

Answer (score 1):

(Two answers included here)

My first thought was

> Iron

I can make you dizzy

> Lack of iron (hemoglobin) in the blood will make you dizzy and lightheaded.

I can ready athletes for games

> *Blood doping* is a common practice, where an athelete sets aside their own red blood cells (**iron**) and adds them before an event.

I can shave sheep

> Shears and clippers were often made of **iron**. (Steel is more common now, but steel is made from **iron**.)

I can show you images on screens

> In old CRT (Cathode Ray Tube) style monitors, an (**iron**) electron gun would shoot electrons at the screen to create the image.

And with my help... you will see the truth when things go wrong

> When you get lost and use a compass, the magnetized **iron** will let you know which way is which.

I can even do a mixture of all these things at the same time

> This one is a little vague, but I suppose an athelete could be dizzy from lack of hemoglobin while lost on his way to a blood doping session before his televised event.  I don't know.  :)

And yet despite all of these things which I can do
I do not have the heart or soul to be able to move anyone or anything

> Iron is inanimate.  Also, it is the element with the highest binding energy per nucleon.  Elements with nucleii lighter than iron can be fused to release energy, elements heavier than iron can release energy when their nucleii are split.  (It does not contribute energy in fusion or fission reactions).

Then someone told me the answer was wrong.  So here is my ***second attempt***:

> Shear

I can make you dizzy

> Wind shear can make you dizzy

I can ready athletes for games

> Swimmers shave before an event

I can shave sheep

> You shave sheep with shears.

I can show you images on screens

> LCD monitors take advantage of shear...

And with my help... you will see the truth when things go wrong

> Umm....

I can be represented by a film

> The Matrix:  Shear can be represented by a shear matrix.

Comment: Sorry, not the right answer. It's not math related too.

Comment: I figured, but I thought I'd put it up anyway, I know the real answer now though. :D   Check the second half.  How's that?

Comment: Still not there, sry.

Comment: Wrong answer, or incomplete explanation?

Comment: Wrong answer, I'm afraid, although you can use some of the ideas in it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A grid

1. > Not sure
2. > Grid can be used for Atheletes to incorporate speed, skill and strategy in a test of endurance through a variety of weightlifting and body-weight elements.
3. > not sure
4. > grids can be used for X-rays
5. > referring to smart grids

Comment: No, too far off (since the other gaps can't be filled).